# How to correctly change the internal state of a closure in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking into closures, but I am a bit confused on how to change their internal state.

Consider the following two examples:

```
def mean():
    sample = []

    def inner_mean(number):
        sample.append(number)
        return sum(sample) / len(sample)

    return inner_mean
```

and

```
def lpf(fs):
    y = 0.0

    def _lpf(fc, u):
        y = (1 - fc / fs) * y + fc / fs * u
        return y

    return _lpf
```

The first case runs without any problem, whereas the second gives me that *variable 'y' in enclosing scope is referenced before assignment*.

Why this won't happen in the first example? And how shall I modify the second example to make it work?

To be more clear, once I created a function I want the value of the internal state `y` to be remembered at each function call.

For example, if do the following:

```
lpf_zero_three = lpf(0.3)

lpf_zero_three(1.2, 0.2)  
lpf_zero_three(1.2, 3.1)
```

the returned value of  `lpf_zero_three(1.2, 3.1)` call shall depend on the value `y` obtained from call of `lpf_zero_three(1.2, 0.2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because there is an assignment to `y` in the inner function (i.e. there is `y =`). This causes a new local variable named `y` to be created, which hides the outer variable `y`.

There is `y` also on the right-hand side of `y=`. That references the same local `y`, which is not initialized yet.

Since your intention is to use the outer variable `y` instead of creating a new inner variable, you should put this at the beginning of function `_lpf`:

```
nonlocal y
```

In the other example, there's no problem because there is no assignment to `sample`.